# "the Man", "men", "humans", "humanity" or "people"?

Tags: word-usage

Is there any guidance on when to use "the Man", "men", "humans", "humanity" and "people"?

I am making this simple sentence and have no idea which word would fit in better:

1. At that time, **humanity** did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact which is now known to every schoolchild.
2. At that time, **the Man** did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact which is now known to every schoolchild.
3. At that time, **men** did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact which is now known to every schoolchild.
4. At that time, **humans** did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact which is now known to every schoolchild.
5. At that time, **people** did not yet know that the earth was round, a fact which is now known to every schoolchild.

Comment: _The man_ sounds like a reference to one particular person. It used to be commonplace to use _man[kind]_ or _men_ to mean 'human beings in general', but this usage is now frowned on as excluding women.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not "The man" (this is an idiom for social control)

I'd prefer not to use "men" because that sounds as if women did know.

I don't like "humanity". We don't have a collective mind.

That leaves "humans" and "people" which are possible... but beg the question "what else is there that could have knowledge?"

So best advice is to rephrase, with "nobody" or use a passive

> Nobody yet knew that the Earth was round

> It was not yet known that the Earth was round.